# Div position fixed causes scrollbar to get hidden behind it

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my webpage which I've positioned fixed -

```
<div class="dropdown-options" style="display: none; height: 61px; position: fixed; left: 18%; width: 500px; top: 50px; background-color: #f7f7f7; z-index: 1; width: 100%;" id="dropdown">
    <table class="navigation nav-collapse" style="height: 61px;">
        ...
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

The style - `left: 0;` has been applied because there is a sidebar to the left occupying 18% width of the page.

I want the div to take the full width of it's parent, so the width is set to 100%.
The problem is - This div hides the scrollbar behind it whenever it is displayed ( via JS ). 
Here are the screenshots of the problem -

When the div is not shown -
[image: When the div is not shown]

When the div is shown -
[image: When the div is shown]

How can I show it such that the scroll bar doesn't get hidden ?

Comment: Try to make it `right: 0;` and `left: 0;` instead.

Comment: `left: 0;` is not applicable because there is a sidebar to the left occupying 18% width of the page. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Still, I tried `left: 0; right: 0;` but it is not working

Comment: Your div is actually positionned as `fixed` not `absolute`... Try making a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Or give an example link. It is quite hard to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I made a fiddle, and it's working properly there. I found that it's parent div was out of place and had a fixed width, so on adding `width: 100%` to the parent div, it's working fine
I've updated the question and corrected the mistake of specifying the position as absolute

Comment: `z-index:-1;` could work?